# IIS 7 - Multiple bindings on one website, redirecting to separate virtual directories

Tags: asp.net, iis

Is there any way of adding multiple bindings to the same website, and have each binding redirect to a different virtual directory on that same website?

E.g. http://application1.some.thing redirecting to application1.some.thing/application1 and http://application2.some.thing redirecting to http://application2.some.thing/application2

Comment: Sounds possible using url rewrites